Usage of Jiffle functions in GeoTools
I'm getting an exception when using Jiffle functions, must I do something else with my script sent to Jiffle?
GridCoverage2DReader reader = lr.getReader();
try {
    Path fileToDeletePath = Paths.get(txtNewFilename.getText());
    GridCoverage2D inCov = reader.read(null);
    Process jiffle =  (Process) Processors.createProcess(new NameImpl("ras", "Jiffle"));
    Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<>();
    inputs.put(JiffleProcess.IN_SOURCE_NAME, new String[] {"a"});
    inputs.put(JiffleProcess.IN_COVERAGE, new GridCoverage2D[] {inCov});
    String scr = "maximum = max(a[0]); ";
    inputs.put(JiffleProcess.IN_SCRIPT, scr);
    Map<String, Object> output = ((org.geotools.process.Process) jiffle).execute(inputs, null);

Resulting in exception:
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.geotools.process.ProcessException: it.geosolutions.jaiext.jiffle.parser.InternalCompilerException: Internal compiler error
at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:649)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.raster.ColorStretcher.tiffSaver(ColorStretcher.java:519)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.raster.ColorStretcher.access$7(ColorStretcher.java:462)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.raster.ColorStretcher$5.actionPerformed(ColorStretcher.java:289)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: it.geosolutions.jaiext.jiffle.parser.InternalCompilerException: Internal compiler error
    at it.geosolutions.jaiext.jiffle.parser.AbstractModelWorker.setFunctionCall(AbstractModelWorker.java:184)
    at it.geosolutions.jaiext.jiffle.parser.AbstractModelWorker.exitFunctionCall(AbstractModelWorker.java:214)
    at it.geosolutions.jaiext.jiffle.parser.SourcePositionsWorker.exitFunctionCall(SourcePositionsWorker.java:33)
    at it.geosolutions.jaiext.jiffle.parser.JiffleParser$FunctionCallContext.exitRule(JiffleParser.java:2172)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.exitRule(ParseTreeWalker.java:47)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:30)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
    at it.geosolutions.jaiext.jiffle.parser.BaseWorker.walkTree(BaseWorker.java:66)
    at it.geosolutions.jaiext.jiffle.parser.SourcePositionsWorker.<init>(SourcePositionsWorker.java:58)
    at it.geosolutions.jaiext.jiffle.Jiffle.getReadPositions(Jiffle.java:745)
    at org.geotools.process.raster.JiffleProcess.getTransformationBands(JiffleProcess.java:371)
    at org.geotools.process.raster.JiffleProcess.getRenderingTransformationBandTransform(JiffleProcess.java:233)
    at org.geotools.process.raster.JiffleProcess.execute(JiffleProcess.java:166)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:633)
    ... 38 more

The exception occurs in AbstractModelWorker, where fnName = "max":
private void setFunctionCall(ParseTree ctx, String fnName, List<ExpressionContext> ecs) {
    try {
        set(ctx, FunctionCall.of(fnName, asExpressions(ecs)));
    } catch (NodeException ex) {
        throw new InternalCompilerException();
    }
}

Btw, Jiffle works with this script;
String scr = "s = max(1, 2); "; 
scr = scr + "dest[0] = a[0]*s; ";
scr = scr + "dest[1] = a[1]; ";
scr = scr + "dest[2] = a[2];";

but not with:
String scr = "s = max(a[0]); "; 
scr = scr + "dest[0] = a[0]*s; ";
scr = scr + "dest[1] = a[1]; ";
scr = scr + "dest[2] = a[2];";

